# Bootstrap 3 remove middle two breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to remove the middle two breakpoints in Bootstrap 3 and have the browser visually "scale/shrink" the page, so in those breakpoints you don't have to scroll left or right to see the page?

Basically, I have a design that I want to be responsive, but only be responsive for the small breakpoint and the large breakpoint, but I don't want a viewer to have to scroll left or right to see all the content.

Here is an example that I'm working on that doesn't work. I've tested on the iPad and I have to scroll around left and right to see the content:
http://matthewtbrown.com/test/myprojects.html

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I don't understand whay you mean

Comment: If you go here, you can see it visually: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=j0z3g0&s=9#.WLIHxhIrKV4

Comment: That doesn't help to explain. Also, you shouldn't have a `container` inside a `container-fluid`. Use one or the other.

Comment: I want the page to scale on an iPad

Comment: It will scale if you just use `container`

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked your code via `Developer Tools`, you're using `container-fluid` for the parent container.

When using `container-fluid` you should use `row-fluid` instead of `row`.

We use `row` when using `container` and `row-fluid` when using `container-fluid`.

It should be something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `row-fluid` since 2.x